# URI Does not exist Dart Analysis - Still builds and runs

Tags: dart, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 2017.2 
(172.3317.70, built on July 14, 2017) And the latest stable release of Dart (1.24.2) and I am receiving errors for almost of my imports (except dart core packages eg. `dart:async`):

```
error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:charted/charted.dart'.
```

I have run `pub get` within WebStorm, and tried `pub upgrade` and `pub get` via command line as well. When this did not work I also tried `pub cache repair` with no prevail.

The errors seem to only affect Webstorm, the application builds with no problems and all packages work fine when using `pub build` in terminal. This problem only arose when I upgraded dart and Webstorm.

When I make changes to the project the analysis server has to catch up, and will often change its mind about whether or not the URI error persists.

Since I have made no changes to my pubspec.yaml files or the project itself, and the project still builds fine in cmd line, is this a potential bug?

**[UPDATE]**: I reverted to the old version of dart sdk, and immediately ran `pub get` and everything worked. I then reverted back to the latest version making sure to run `pub get` right away, and it seems to be cooperating.

**[UPDATE 2]**: Issue is definitely recurring. Very hit or miss, currently still have the errors.

Comment: You could try to delete the `.pub` directory in your project directory. I also had this a few times a while back. I'm on 1.25.0-dev.x now though.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but gave that a try and still no luck.  I may just roll back to a working version or try the dev version as this problem really affects the functionality of Webstorm.

Comment: I know this issue is old, but if it's still persisting, please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ (because this looks like a WebStorm issue).